# Path specs and multiple servlets

Tags: servlets, spring-mvc, jetty

I'd like to have two servlets (I'm using Jetty) serve URLs like this:

```
host/aaa/submit  
host/bbb/submit
```

I've tried setting the servlets' pathspecs to `aaa` and `bbb` respectively, but then I get an exception along the lines of

```
two controller methods annotated with @RequestMapping(value = {"/submit"})
```

(even though the two methods in question are defined in two separate controller classes that are used by two different servlets).
if instead I set both servlets' pathspecs to `/` and change the `@RequestMappings` to `aaa/submit` and `bbb/submit`, I'm getting 404s. (This, I suppose, is less surprising - not sure how it should work with effectively two 'default' servlets)

How should I map those URLs? (preemptively - they **do** need to be separate servlets - `aaa` part should work with or without DB, `bbb` part should fail without DB)

Just in case, here's the Jetty context:

```
    <property name="servletHandler">
        <bean class="org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler">
            <property name="servlets">
                <list>
                    <bean name="aaaServlet" class="org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder">
                        <property name="name" value="aaa" />
                        <property name="servlet">
                            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet" />
                        </property>
                        <property name="initParameters">
                            <map>
                                <entry key="contextConfigLocation" value="classpath:aaa-context.xml" />
                            </map>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                    <bean name="bbbServlet" class="org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder">
                        <property name="name" value="bbb" />
                        <property name="servlet">
                            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet" />
                        </property>
                        <property name="initParameters">
                            <map>
                                <entry key="contextConfigLocation" value="classpath:bbb-context.xml" />
                            </map>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="servletMappings">
                <list>
                    <bean class="org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletMapping">
                        <property name="servletName" value="aaa" />
                        <property name="pathSpec" value="/" />
                    </bean>
                    <bean class="org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletMapping">
                        <property name="servletName" value="bbb" />
                        <property name="pathSpec" value="/" />
                    </bean>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
```

And the two controllers that look like this:

```
@Controller
public class AaaController {
  @RequestMapping(value = {"/aaa/submit"}, method = (RequestMethod.POST))
  public void handleAaaSubmitPostRequest(final HttpServletRequest request,
                                       final HttpServletResponse response,
                                       @RequestBody String body) throws IOException {
}
```

And

```
@Controller
public class BbbController {
  @RequestMapping(value = {"/bbb/submit"}, method = (RequestMethod.POST))
  public void handleBbbSubmitPostRequest(final HttpServletRequest request,
                                       final HttpServletResponse response,
                                       @RequestBody String body) throws IOException {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your controllers seem to be in different mvc-contexts, you need to change your controller according to this:

```
@Controller
public class AaaController {
  @RequestMapping(value = {/*aaa*/"/submit"}, method = (RequestMethod.POST))
  public void handleAaaSubmitPostRequest(final HttpServletRequest request,
                                       final HttpServletResponse response,
                                       @RequestBody String body) throws IOException {
}
```

and

```
    @Controller
public class BbbController {
  @RequestMapping(value = {/*bbb*/"/submit"}, method = (RequestMethod.POST))
  public void handleBbbSubmitPostRequest(final HttpServletRequest request,
                                       final HttpServletResponse response,
                                       @RequestBody String body) throws IOException {
}
```

This happens because Spring MVC is always using path without servlet context.

Comment: I assume that you mean I should also set the path specs of the servlets to `/aaa/*` and `/bbb/*`. I cover this case in my question - upon startup I get an exception like this: `Cannot map handler 'bbbController' to URL path [/submit]: There is already handler of type [class AaaController] mapped.`

Comment: Then please make sure that you are having your controllers accessible only in different mvc contexts, e.g. `AaaController` in `aaa-context.xml` and `BbbController` in `bbb-context.xml` only. Otherwise I would recommend using single context with path "/" and your initial `@RequestMapping` solution will work.

Comment: BTW, in your current configuration such URLs are accessible: `aaa/aaa/submit`, `aaa/bbb/submit`, `bbb/bbb/submit` and `bbb/aaa/submit`, isn't it so?